# changing the image in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

i have this jquery code which works fine, but the image at the end is not changing to the src i specified here:

jquery:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $("a.vote_up").click(function(){
        //get the id
        var the_id = $(this).attr('id');

        //the main ajax request
        $.ajax( {
          type: "POST",
          data: "action=vote_up&id=" + the_id,
          url: "ajax/votes.php",
          success: function( msg ) {
            $("span.vote_count#"+the_id).html(msg).fadeIn();
// my problem is here 
            $(".vote_up#" + the_id + " img").attr("src", "img/upvoteActive.png");
          }
        } );
      } );
    } );
```

the html code:

```
<a href='#' class='vote_up' id="$id"><img src="img/uparrow.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use class in combination with ID; it is redundant because ID should always be unique...

```
 $("#" + the_id + " img").attr("src", "img/upvoteActive.png");
```

Also, you cannot use the character $ in the ID attribute.  To quote the [W3C on the ID attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name)...

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

Comment: +1; Just because it didn't work for you there is no need to down vote because the answer still makes a good point.

Comment: but its unrelevant, he should use the commenting system, its not an answer, its advice!!!

Comment: @getaway It is not irrelevant, it is the correct answer.  Read the first sentence.  ID SHOULD ALWAYS BE UNIQUE.  This is an answer, not advice, and I shall now place your username down in the "people NOT to help" category.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the same ID multiple times (img and count). Try making the ID more unique like:

```
<a href='#' class='vote_up' id="$id_link"><img src="img/uparrow.png" /></a>
<span class="vote_count" id="$id_count"></span>
```

Comment: You can't make something 'more unique'. It's either unique... or it's not.</pedant>